# Union of several linestring to multilinestring using MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The following PostgreSQL query is the existing one used to combine several linestrings to a single multilinestring.

Is there any equivalent of this in SQL Server?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(
 
ARRAY[
 
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)'),
                ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3 4, 4 5)')
]
)) As wktcollect;
```

This is the sample query . My input will be multiples of Linestrings . (Eg: LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)) which comes dynamically .

Executing this in PostgreSQL will get a clubbed  Linestrings as  single MultiLinestrings .

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Server 2012 and higher:**
I couldn't work out a way to cleanly do this with geometry methods alone.  The closest I could get was to use CollectionAggregate and then do string replaces on the WKT. This will break if the LINESTRINGS overlap, at which point you would be using `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` anyway.

```
with gcte as
(
    select geometry::STGeomFromText ('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)', 0) as geom
    union all
    select geometry::STGeomFromText ('LINESTRING(3 4, 4 5)', 0) as geom
)
select  (geometry::UnionAggregate(geom)).STAsText() as Unioned, (geometry::CollectionAggregate(geom)).STAsText() as Collected
,Replace(Replace((geometry::CollectionAggregate(geom)).STAsText() collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,'LINESTRING',''),'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION','MULTILINESTRING') as MLINESTRING
,(geometry::STGeomFromText(Replace(Replace((geometry::CollectionAggregate(geom)).STAsText() collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,'LINESTRING',''),'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION','MULTILINESTRING'),0)) MultiLinestringGeom
from gcte;
```

[image]